# Protect sensitive data in embedded devices?

Tags: security, encryption, embedded

What is the safest way to store sensitive data on an embedded device?

At my job, I am developing a product for the consumer market, it will have an eMMC card, with very valuable data in it. I want to know what is the best way to protect this data, ie make it impossible for someone to understand its content. (ps: this is not code, this is an actual data set)

The way I imagine the design is to put the data on the eMMC, encrypt it with AES (128bit key is enough?). The keys will be stored on the flash memory of the MCU. The MCU I use provide functionalities to prevent flash read-out, and flash overwrite. However, the eMMC with the data (but without the encryption key) will be available to a hacker if he just hard-wires the eMMC to its computer.
Therefore the decrypted data will only temporary live in the RAM of the system.

So, if I correctly use the functionality of my MCU to lock the flash memory, will it be safe? Or is there other ways to fetch the content of the flash memory (embedded into the MCU) every if its protected? Like hardware mods or things like this. Or is it possible to make something of the data even if I successfully hide the key in the flash memory?

Please, avoid answers like "... *should be fine*." I would like to have an idea of the worst case scenarios.

For reference, here is the read-out/write protection functionality of the MCU we use, but my question has a general purpose, not necessarily tied to one MCU.
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/89/12/c5/e2/0d/0e/45/7f/DM00186528.pdf/files/DM00186528.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00186528.pdf

Comment: In general, if a ciphertext (that's your dataset) and its corresponding decryption key reside on the same device, then that device is said to contain the plaintext.  Just something to think about.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to access any bit of information on the MCU, given enough time/money.   If security is really important, you need to hire/contract a security expert and not essentially ask random people on the internet about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely depended on the functionality of your device (or your secure information).
Generally AES-128 bit encryption is enough for reasonable grade of security in embedded devices.
But storing keys in non-protected memory(processor's flash memory) cause a serious security matters,There are many Physical/Logical ways for extracting data from non-volatile memory.

You can Store your keys in general SRAM memory and protect system with tamper detection keys,or use MCU with built-in crypto co-processor and secure key storing(e.g. lpc18s,lpc43s and etc.)or use a external cryptographer chip like TPM or SAM for boosting your security level.
But as said it before at first you must decide how & when you need to en/decrypt 
data , Is this needed to transmit plain data(decrypted information) in unsecured data lines?
You can receive more information in below link which I asked a while ago:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198274/storing-a-secure-key-in-an-embedded-devices-memory

Answer (score 3):

I have worked with the development of credit card machines, the most common attacks were:

1. Human resource leak, when an engineer leaked sensitive data or inserted backdoors to the product. This is not related to your question, I wont expand.
2. Software hacking, where the attacker will try to download your firmware and or try to grant "root" access exploiting JTAG, UART, ethernet, USB and any other port your product may have. It doesn't matter how secure your key is, if they get a JTAG to run on it the key shall be easily recovered. Same with a root console via serial, or if they are able to download, hack and reprogram your flash.
3. Bus sniffing, where the attacker will plug spies into your buses (mmc, spi, uart, etc... even on memory such as DDR3 bus) to spy on data. If you transfer your sensitive data unencrypted into a bus that can be spyed, it is a security breach. To avoid that you should bury your buses into the PCB and use BGAs only, do net let it accessible in outer layers.
4. Encrypt everything. There's been attacks where memory chips were hatched (physically!) and bit states were read visually by a microscope!

This is the order of the most common attacks I have known of.

You could always use secure chips, secure bootloaders and tamper traps to erase the whole thing in case of abuse.

Comment: "you should bury your buses into the PCB" This sounds like questionable practice; anyone with a scalpel could dig up the inner layers, or if they are smart, sniff at the PCB vias. Even if you use blind vias, those could get dug up too.

Comment: Lundin, true. Forgot to mention that outer layers should also contain an anti tamper mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Security costs depend on how valuable is the data it's protecting. If it's really that valuable go for a [Secure Cryptoprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cryptoprocessor) with Tamper Resistance.

Basically are devices that somehow "break" on event physical tampering, and also try to prevent indirect sniffing of signals.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the usage for your data.

If your embedded device also needs the data you need to use a **symetric key**.

If you only want to store the data, but the device itself doesn't need to read it anymore you should use an **asymetric key**.
Then it's impossible to recover the data, even with the full content of the flash.
It's not to hard implement this with a good library.

But there are problems left.
It's still possible to fetch the data while it's produced.
How this can be avoided depends on your system design.